# Null result when converting String to Date format in Databricks SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a String column from a temp view, were dates values are stored in format of '2020/01/01'.
I do need to convert that field to a date value to be stored into a Delta table in 'YYY-MM-DD' format.
I've been trying different kind of SQL functions but none of them seems to works, as a result, every function retrieves a null value:

```
select to_date(dateField, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
       CAST(dateField as date),
       etc..
from TMP_table
```

Every function results in a null value, and there's no information about that into Databricks documentation.

Comment: Tried `'yyyy/DD/mm'`?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Usagi said above, `select to_date(dateField, 'yyyy/MM/dd') AS date` works perfectly.